# Dynamic filtering for multiple conditions pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe with 5 columns, 10k of rows and all data is integer. The dataframe looks like this :

```
Item_code#  Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5
02516       3       1       10      21      7
03382       23      12      4       5       31
05921       20      3       1       11      25
82433       3       12      20      21      33
```

I need to get rid of rows which don’t carry all three integers let‘s say  1,3 & 10. The order of each integer whether it appears in column1, or column2 is to be ignored in this case.

Any idea on how to do this filtering?

**EDIT**

From this dataframe only item code 02516, 04599 and 85345 are to be kept:

```
Item_code#  Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4  Column5
2516        3        1        10       21       7
3382        23       12       4        5        31
5921        20       3        1        11       25
82433       3        12       20       21       33
1455        1        1        3        25       6
4599        3        10       15       1        21
85345       0        1        3        3        10
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using [isin](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) and [any](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html]) pandas dataframe methods:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = """
Item_code#  Column1 Column2    Column3    Column4    Column5
02516       3       1       10      21      7
03382       23      12      4       5       31
05921       20      3       1       11      25
82433       3       12      20      21      33
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\s+')
match_list = [1, 3, 10]
df1 = df[df.isin(match_list).any(axis=1)]
print(df1)

   Item_code#  Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4  Column5
0        2516        3        1       10       21        7
2        5921       20        3        1       11       25
3       82433        3       12       20       21       33
```

**EDIT**

If you need to match them all you could try to use sum method:

```
df1 = df[df.isin(match_list).sum(axis=1) == len(match_list)]

print(df1)
Item_code#  Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4  Column5
0        2516        3        1       10       21        7
```

**EDIT2**

For your edit you could do following:

```
data = """
Item_code#  Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 
02516 3 1 10  21  7 
03382 23  12  4 5 31 
05921  20 3  1 11  25 
82433  3 12  20  21  33 
01455  1 1 3 25  6 
04599 3 10  15  1 21 
85345  0 1 3 3 10
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\s+')

match_list = [1, 3, 10]
df1 = df[df.isin(match_list).sum(axis=1) >= len(match_list)]

In [26]: print(df1)
   Item_code#  Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4  Column5
0        2516        3        1       10       21        7
4        1455        1        1        3       25        6
5        4599        3       10       15        1       21
6       85345        0        1        3        3       10
```

Comment: I see this script  filter out rows which contain either one or two or all of the given integers. i need rows which have all three given integers altogether in the same row.

Comment: Anton I think i have missed to mention on my question that my data can have more than one same integer among its columns - let's say it has integer 3 on both column 2 & column 4. Unfortunately the edited version does not work for this purpose.

Comment: @SmoothJourney could you provide appropriate dataframe example?

Comment: Item code# Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5
02516 3 1 10 21 7
03382 23 12 4 5 31
05921 20 3 1 11 25
82433 3 12 20 21 33
01455 1 1 3 25 6
04599 3 10 15 1 21
85345 0 1 3 3 10  From this dataframe only rows with item code 02516,04599 and 85345 are to be kept.

Comment: @SmoothJourney it's better if you will update your answer and attach that example of dataframe

Comment: Item code# Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5
02516 3 1 10 21 7
03382 23 12 4 5 31
05921 20 3 1 11 25
82433 3 12 20 21 33
01455 1 1 3 25 6
04599 3 10 15 1 21
85345 0 1 3 3 10
From this dataframe only item code 02516,04599 and 85345 are to be kept.